# Auto-upload generated documentation on Github

Tags: java, git, bash, github, travis-ci

I've a big Java project with Javadoc comments on Github. There is Travis CI linked on it. After a success, I want to generate the documentation of the project and push it on a branch called... "doc" !

There is a bash script launched after a successful build on Travis CI :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# If error, return 0
set -e

# Repo
REPOSITORY="git@github.com:xxx/yyy"

# Clone repo to work in (repo_clone dir)
git clone ${REPOSITORY} repo_clone
cd repo_clone

# Go into doc branch, create it if not exist (first time only)
git checkout doc || git checkout --orphan doc

git config user.name "Travis CI"
git config user.email "doc@backtothefuture.go"

# Generation of doc
javadoc -private -sourcepath "src/main/java:src/main/ressources" \
      -d doc \
      marche.traitement.exceptions \
      marche.traitement.label \
      marche.traitement.marche \
      marche.traitement.participant \
      marche.traitement.production \
      marche.traitement.produits

# Add new dir (all dir but only doc/ is impacted
git add .

git commit -m "There is the doc Marty !"

git remote add origin ${REPOSITORY}

# Push
git push origin doc
```

But sometimes I've this error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Sometimes this one :

```
error: src refspec doc does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:GeeksdelaCave/aidons-les-fermiers.git'
```

Depending of minors adaptations.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not going to test this, but i think this will work. the first `checkout` and first `push` will give errors if the `doc` branch already exists on the remote, but without consequence:

```
...
git checkout -b doc || git checkout doc

# Add new dir (all dir but only doc/ is impacted
git add .

git commit -m "There is the doc Marty !"

git push -u origin doc
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

The origin remote is set automatically when cloning a repository. So after

```
git clone ${REPOSITORY} repo_clone
```

you already have a remote called `origin` pointing to `git@github.com:xxx/yyy`. This explains the first error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that does this.
You can find my example [here](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/blob/master/.travis-scripts/push-javadoc-to-gh-pages.sh)

The code raw can be found here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source of file: http://benlimmer.com/2013/12/26/automatically-publish-javadoc-to-gh-pages-with-travis-ci/
if [ "$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG" == "WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION" == "oraclejdk8" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ] && [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" != "osx" ]]; then

  echo -e "Generating javadoc...\n"
  ./gradlew aggregateJavadocs

  echo -e "Publishing javadoc...\n"

  cp -R build/docs/javadoc $HOME/javadoc-latest

  cd $HOME
  git config --global user.email "travis@travis-ci.org"
  git config --global user.name "travis-ci"
  git clone --quiet --branch=gh-pages https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/grip gh-pages #> /dev/null

  cd gh-pages
  git rm -rf ./javadoc
  cp -Rf $HOME/javadoc-latest ./javadoc
  git add -f .
  git commit -m "Lastest javadoc on successful travis build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER auto-pushed to gh-pages"
  git push -fq origin gh-pages #> /dev/null

  echo -e "Published Javadoc to gh-pages.\n"

fi
```